# How does C handle sign extension?

Tags: c, unsigned, signed

I have a pointer to a buffer of bytes from which I am copying every even indexed bytes to an int(because of the protocol that the data is stored into buffer I know the odd cycles are for read).
Now when I do this

```
signed int a;
...
//inside a loop
a = buffer[2*i]; //buffer is unsigned
```

It gives me an unsigned number. However when I do this

```
a = (int8_t)buffer[2*i]
```

the number is presented in signed form. That is forcing me to rethink how sign extension in c work, especially in scenarios like above. 
My understanding was since I am declaring a as signed, compiler will automatically do the sign extension. Can anybody take some time to explain why this is not the case. I just spent an hour in this trap and don't want to fall in the same trap in future again.

Comment: good read http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/signExt.html

Comment: I  know how sign extension works in C, but in a case when you have an unsigned number (but "sign bit" is 1) and you are sign extending by casting to longer integer, how is that handled? Sorry if that was not clear from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buffer` is an array of unsigned eight-bit integers (or acts as one). So the value of `buffer[2*i]` is in the range from 0 to 255 (inclusive), and all values in that range are representable as `int`s, so assigning

```
a = buffer[2*i];
```

preserves the value, the promotion to the wider type `int` is done by padding with zeros.

If you cast to `int8_t` before assigning,

```
a = (int8_t)buffer[2*i]
```

values in the buffer larger than 127 are converted in an implementation-defined way to type `int8_t`, most likely by just reinterpreting the bit-pattern as a signed 8-bit integer, which results in a negative value, from -128 to -1. These values are representable as `int`s, so they are preserved in the assignment, the value-preserving promotion to the wider type `int` is then done by sign-extension.

Answer (score 1):

An int_8 only has 8 bits, if the highest bit is 1 it holds a negative value : 1xxxxxxx , if you assign such  a value to a signed int(32 or 64 bits), of course you would get a negative value. the longer int would look like `11111111 11111111 11111111 1xxxxxxx` after the assignment, just a simple xor would do the trick 00000000 ^ 1001 => 11111001.