# little endian to uint with undetermined numbers of bytes

Tags: c, endianness

I was trying to write a function that took in N bytes of little endian hex and made it into an unsigned int.

```
unsigned int endian_to_uint(char* buf, int num_bytes)
{
    if (num_bytes == 0)
            return (unsigned int) buf[0];

    return (((unsigned int) buf[num_bytes -1]) << num_bytes * 8) | endian_to_uint(buf, num_bytes - 1);
}
```

however, the value returned is approx ~256 times larger than the expected value. Why is that?

If I needed to do use it for a 4 byte buffer, normally you'd do:

```
unsigned int endian_to_uint32(char* buf)
{
    return (((unsigned int) buf[3]) <<   24)
         | (((unsigned int) buf[2]) <<   16)
         | (((unsigned int) buf[1]) << 8)
         | (((unsigned int) buf[0]));
}
```

which should be reproduced by the recursive function I wrote, or is there some arithmetic error that I haven't caught?

Comment: Show how you are calling the function

Comment: Your second example shows a 4 byte value. How far would you shift that same value in your first function if 4 was passed as the length? The fact that it's 256 times larger should give you a clue. What is shifting left 8 bits?

Comment: Basically you have off-by-one errors in the function. If you call with argument 4, you're doing `buf[3] << 32 | buf[2] << 24 | buf[1] << 16 | buf[0] << 8 | buf[0]`

Comment: @M.M you are correct, I thought I had tested for that in one of my earlier tests, but I hadn't accounted for the shift value

Comment: Why use recursion for this? Do you have some kind of aversion against fast, safe and readable programs?

Comment: @Lundin Let's be honest here. C is a dangerous language because it has little user security built in to it. C has a lot of functionalities that were implemented just because they were looking for power, as such, if you are using C to write programs, but you are deliberately avoiding all the things that is a little bit unsafe or affects readability, I would suggest that you switch to another language. By definition, generality is based on the power of a language, because it allows the programmer to apply a specific solution to a general problem and expand from there.

Comment: @Ohunter Except recursion is not powerful. It is the weakest and slowest of language features. C was given recursion mostly because recursion was possible in assembler, but also since adding as many (often pointless) features as possible to every language was popular back then. And in assembler, it is mostly a dirty hack, since nothing's stopping you from calling a function from within the same function. Then some theoretical math person found out about this hack and started to use it to implement mathematical recursion. From there on, it is all history of famous bugs through the ages.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your statement. First, you cannot say that recursion isn't powerful because it leads to bugs. Second, you say that recursion is a dirty hack and that it isn't powerful because it is slow? Isn't the very definition of powerful that it allows you to do something with few lines of code, and wouldn't a dirty hack have a somewhat similar definition? There are so many things that if you wanted to implement them without recursion development time would be several magnitudes larger compared to what you could achieve with recursion. Again, that's power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code snippet would work.

```
unsigned int endian_to_uint(unsigned char* buf, int num_bytes)
{
    if (num_bytes == 0)
        return (unsigned int) buf[0];

    return (((unsigned int) buf[num_bytes -1]) << (num_bytes -1) * 8) | endian_to_uint(buf, num_bytes - 1);
}
```

**Change 1:**
Modified the function argument data type from `char*` to `unsigned char *`
Reason:
 For a given `buf[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0xab, 0xcd};` 
When you are trying to read `buf[3]` i.e here `buf[num_bytes -1]` will give you `0xffffffcd` instead of just `0xcd` because of sign extension. For more info on sign extension refer [Sign Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999484/how-does-c-handle-sign-extension)

**Change 2:**
Use `num_bytes-1` when calculating the shift position value. This was a logical error in calculation of the number of bits to be shifted.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use recursion here: bit shifts is among the fastest operations available, recursion is among the slowest. In addition, recursion is dangerous, hard to read and gives nasty peak stack consumption. It should be avoided in general.

In addition, your function is not a general one, since you return `unsigned int`, making the function inferior to the shift version in every single way.

To actually write a generic-size little endian conversion function, you can do like this:

```
void little_endian (size_t bytes, uint8_t dest[bytes], const uint8_t src[bytes])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<bytes; i++)
  {
    dest[i] = src[bytes-i-1];
  }
}
```

Working example:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void little_endian (size_t bytes, uint8_t dest[bytes], const uint8_t src[bytes])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<bytes; i++)
  {
    dest[i] = src[bytes-i-1];
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  uint8_t data [] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88};
  uint32_t u32;
  uint64_t u64;

  little_endian(4, (uint8_t*)&u32, data);
  little_endian(8, (uint8_t*)&u64, data);

  printf("%"PRIx32"\n", u32);
  printf("%"PRIx64"\n", u64);

  return 0;
}
```